# Continuing code execution after error in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, trace, flashlog

I want to be able to throw an error to be traced to the trace output window and to my flashlog.txt file but continue code execution after the error. Is this possible in Actionscript 3? A try catch will not work either because I need the error to be logged with its call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by trace output window you mean the window that pops up when an Error is thrown (as opposed to the trace window in the Flash IDE, Flash Builder, etc), there's a bit hackish workaround. Basically, you have to delay the call to `throw` so it runs in its own stack call.

Something like this should do it:

```
    public static function throwLater(error:Error):void 
    {
        setTimeout(function():void {
            throw error;
        },30);
    }
```

Of course you have to pass the error to this function, instead of throwing it directly.

If you just want to get the stack trace from an existent error, though, catch it and get the stack trace as [The_asMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654423/the-asman) showed.

```
        try {
            thisFunctionMightThrow()
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace(e.getStackTrace();
        }
```

Also, if you just want to have the stack trace at some point (but don't want to actually throw an error), just create the error and call `getStackTrace`, without throwing. In this case, you don't really need a catch.

```
        var error:Error = new Error();
        trace(e.getStackTrace());
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will work in a try catch just put this code in the catch block

```
var e:Error = new Error(“Some error”);
trace(e.getStackTrace());
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will not help you at all if you're publishing as a release version and using the release player.  e.getStackTrace() always returns null if the player isn't a debug player.